# Cannot write to XML from web page

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml

I have written a small application in HTML/CSS/JQuery/XML/XSLT that ends up writing to an XML file located alongside my files on the server. Everything works fine 99% of the time, but som users experience problems when writing to the XML file.

The users that experience problems all use computers located at their working places, which for all users appear to be in large companies, assumably with strict security measures. But still - the XML is on my server, shouldn't really be relevant for the most paranoid system in the world?

Now, I wonder what exactly this can be. What causes this? And how can I detect this problem-users so that I can give them special treatment?

The site can be viewed at www.northcreek.no/em

Comment: You're not using a load-balancing system on your web servers, are you?

Comment: Is there any other domain being referred to in the process? Cause if users are able to see your site, I guess that is able to bypass the firewalls and other security measures, but the other link may be causing the trouble. Else as @Blazemonger suggests there might be a problem with handling of load at your server point.

Comment: I had missed out a "var" keyword in front of a declaration, which I think most browsers forgive, but IE treats as a fatal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all those user use IE, because when I try it in IE I get script-errors and will not be able to finish the final step.

So you first should fix the script-errors.

Comment: Yes, I used the Javascript Validator found at http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php to remove some errors. I hope that will do the trick.

Comment: You've been sended a mail to me this morning, the user "doc" is me, you may remove my data.